# Can I use local yeast to brew beer?

Tags: yeast

I am from Kathmandu, Nepal and I was wondering if I could use local yeast to brew beer.

The yeast I want to use is generally used to make local rice beer called chhaang.

Comment: I would expect it to turn out slightly sour. This is just a guess, I haven't been able to get serious information about the yeast used in chhaang. But be prepared for that. Not everyone likes sour beer (but I do!!!)

Answer (score 6):

You can use any yeast and it will make "beer". Whether this beer is tasty is a whole different issue. If it's your only option, try it! I'll be curious to see how it turns out!

You should definitely consider making a starter, especially if the source of the yeast is questionable.

Answer (score 0):

Baker's yeast and brewers yeast (and wine yeast) are all *[Saccharomyces cerevisiae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saccharomyces_cerevisiae)* and can all be used interchangeably. I have made bread with wine yeast and beer with wine yeast and wine with bread yeast. They will all work to ferment whatever you are trying to do. There shouldn't be any off flavors if you keep everything clean.

I read up on [Chhaang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chhaang) and it appears they just use regular yeast to make it so whatever they are using to make that, I would use that first if it's easy to get.

Answer (score -2):

Actually you are gonna ferment your wort with wild yeast, which is used locally to make some chang or something else. I suggest you to not use this type because it'll form a lot of off flavors, off aromas in your beer due to aldehydes, diaceteldehydes etc.). And the most important thing is the alcohol, because it must produce higher alcohol n methanol which is not good for health atall.

Comment: Where did you get information about attenuation of chhaang rice beer yeast (pab / chanzi) ?

Comment: Certainly the introduction of a foreign yeast will matter for the good or bad.  I accept that certain yeast strains are cultivated around the world and used for specific purposes.  I agree with Daniella.  Try it and see if it is good.  But you are not making beer.  Brewers make wort, yeast makes beer.....so keep the variables to ONLY the yeast to be safe.